# (dd command linux) last byte goes to next line

Tags: linux, bash, mainframe

Hi friends I need some help.

We have a tool that convert binary files to text files, and after that stores into Hadoop (HDFS).

In production, that ingestion tool uses ftp to download files from mainframe in binary format (EBCDIC), and we don't have access to donwload files from mainframe in development environment.

In order to test file conversion, we manually create text files, and we are trying to convert file using dd command (linux), using these parameters:

```
dd if=asciifile.txt of=ebcdicfile conf=ebcdic
```

After pass through our conversion tool, the expected result is:

```
000000000000000               DATA
000000000000000               DATA
000000000000000               DATA
000000000000000               DATA
```

However, it's returning the following result:

```
000000000000000               DAT
A000000000000000               DA
TA000000000000000               D
ATA000000000000000
```

I have tried with cbs, obs and ibs parameters, assigning lrec (number of lines of each line) without success.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read through [ask] and especially [mcve]

Comment: Did you mean to write `conv=ebcdic`?  Also, in what sense is anything binary? Character set conversions don't generally make sense for binary data.  (EBCDIC is a character set, like ASCII, not a file format.)

Comment: And when you say "After pass through our conversion tool", are you talking about the `dd` command alone or something larger?

Comment: yes, the correct parameter is conv=ebcdic, and the conversion tool is a internal company's application

Answer (score 2):

A few things to consider:

1. How exactly is the data transferred via FTP? Your *"in binary format(EBCDIC)"* simply doesn't make any sense at all. The FTP either transfers in *binary format*, then nothing gets changed, or converted during the transfer. Or the FTP transfers in *text mode*, aka. *ASCII mode*, then data is converted from a **specific EBCDIC code page** to a **specific non-EBCDIC code page**. You need to know what mode, and if text mode, what are the two code pages being used.
2. From the man pages for *dd*, it is unclear what *EBCDIC*, and *ASCII code pages* are used for the conversion. I'm just guessing here: EBCDIC code page might be CP-037, and ASCII might be CP-437. If these don't match the ones used in the FTP, the resulting test data is incorrect.
3. I understand you don't have access to production data in the development environment. However, you should still be able to get test data from the development *mainframe* using FTP from there. If not, how will you be doing end to end testing?

Comment: You still need to know what code pages exactly are being used.

Answer (score 1):

The EBCDIC conversion is eating your line endings:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=server-different-end-line-characters-in-text-files